# Rails3 has_many belongs_to scope joins merge isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, merge, scope, rspec2

I'm on Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.2I am trying to use the scope joins/merge syntax to keep my model logic dry. I am having trouble when testing this tho and I'm not sure why.

product.rb:

```
belongs_to :product_status

scope :sellable, -> {joins(:product_status).where('products.quantity_available > 0').merge(ProductStatus.sellable)}
```

product_status.rb:

```
has_many :products

scope :sellable, -> {where("product_statuses.name in ('Active','Deactivated')")}
```

In my tests, testing product status passes:

```
it "should return 0 count without a valid member" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:product_status)
  ProductStatus.sellable.count.should == 0
end

it "should return 1 count with a valid member" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:active_product_status)
  ProductStatus.sellable.count.should == 1
end
```

But I cannot get my product tests to pass:

```
it "should return 1 count with a valid member" do
  active_product_status = FactoryGirl.create(:active_product_status)
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, :product_status => active_product_status)
  Product.sellable.count.should == 1
end
```

The quantity for the product is set to over 0. I've wrote a different scope to just test that part and it passed no problem.

The SQL created by the call looks right to me, but maybe it will show the issue to someone better at this kind of thing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products` INNER JOIN `product_statuses` ON `product_statuses`.`id` = `products`.`product_status_id` WHERE products.quantity_available > 0 AND (product_statuses.name in ('Active','Deactivated'))
```

I added in this to the test to ensure the active_product_status was in fact sellable

```
it "should return 1 count with a valid member" do
  active_product_status = FactoryGirl.create(:active_product_status)
  product = FactoryGirl.create(:product, :product_status => active_product_status)
  ProductStatus.sellable.all.include?(product.product_status).should == true
  Product.sellable.count.should == 1
end
```

And the ProductStatus test passed, just not the Product one.

I've never used the joins/merge syntax before so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I can get it to work if I call it from:

```
ProductStatus.sellable.joins(:products).merge(Product.sellable)
```

but I need to be able to make this call from the product model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.